# How do I use Ajax in a Joomla! site for an Mplayer drop-down P3 instead of an iframe drop-down?

Tags: ajax, iframe, joomla, mp3

How do I use Ajax in a Joomla! site for an Mplayer drop-down P3 instead of an iframe drop-down?

The goal is when someone's playing the MP3  player and browsing through the site  the song stays playing and  each time the page reloads it doesn't start over iframe is doesn't really help that much because it's one thing need something that will work with Joomla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way achieving this using a classic [HTML FrameSet](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html):

1. Create a `FrameSet` with two Frames:

   - Frame 1: Target to your MP3 player web-app
   - Frame 2: Joomla site
2. Modify `.htaccess` to load the custom set of frames when entering
   the site instead of the plain Joomla template. Assuming your
   FrameSet is named start.php

   `DirectoryIndex start.php index.php`

So now whenever a link on your Joomla site is clicked it loads within frame 2. The player in frame 1 keeps playing...   ♩   ♪   ♩ But note that a page refresh via your browsers native button still means that the music stops (as the `FrameSet` is gone). Find some more details in this [German blogpost](http://joomla-extensions.kubik-rubik.de/item/joomla-mit-fortlaufendem-mp3-player) or via [Google translate](http://translate.google.de/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://joomla-extensions.kubik-rubik.de/item/joomla-mit-fortlaufendem-mp3-player).